# Why does not Java HashSet.equals() check for object equality?

Tags: java, list, set, equals, hashset

I've come to this phenomenon this morning, the `equals` method in `Set` does not check for value equality of the element while `List` does. This is not in accordance with the java doc.

```
Set<MyClass> s1 = new HashSet<>();
Set<MyClass> s2 = new HashSet<>();
Set<MyClass> s3 = new HashSet<>();
Set<MyClass> s4 = new HashSet<>();
List<MyClass> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<MyClass> l2 = new ArrayList<>();

MyClass o1 = new MyClass();
MyClass o2 = new MyClass();

// **this gives false, and does not call MyClass.equals().**
s1.add(o1);
s2.add(o2);
boolean setCompareWithDifferentObjects = s1.equals(s2);

// this gives true, and also does not call MyClass.equals().
s3.add(o1);
s4.add(o1);
boolean setCompareWithSaveObjects = s3.equals(s4);

// this give true, and MyClass.equals() is called.
l1.add(o1);
l2.add(o2);
boolean listCompare = l1.equals(l2)
```

I've done some research. According to this 
[Java doc for Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#equals(java.lang.Object)), [HashSet equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSet.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) , [HashSet containsAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#containsAll(java.util.Collection)), [HashSet contains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#contains(java.lang.Object)), it will use (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)) to check whether the elements are equal. So why is this happen? Can anyone give me some hint on this?

Thanks!

----------Answer to this question can be found here -----------

[What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)

I overrided equals() but not hashCode()...

btw, the same set comparison worked in groovy, even if hashCode() is not overriden.

Comment: Have you implemented both equals and hashcode methods properly?

Comment: I've implemented MyClass.equals() but not hashCode(). But in the first comparison, MyClass.equals is not entered at all, even if == fails.

Comment: Sigh... if you have not implemented `hashCode()` this explains everything you are seeing.  `equals()` and `hashCode()` MUST be consistent with each other. Also, please do not retype code into the SO input text box.  Always copy/paste so you don't introduce transcription errors (`l2.add(l2)`).  One such obvious error makes your entire code sample suspect, and leads to unnecessary requests for clarification.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`HashSet` includes a number of optimizations that can explain all of this: first, if two objects are put into different buckets by their hash codes, or if they have different hash codes at all, they may skip the `equals` call.  This is allowed by the contract of `Object.hashCode`; if two objects have different hash codes then they are not allowed to `.equals` to each other.

For the other case, `HashSet` takes advantage of the contract of `.equals` that specifies that if two objects are `==` to each other, then they must be `.equals` to each other.  Part of `HashSet`'s implementation here checks if the elements are `==`, and if they are, it skips calling `.equals`.

If every method implements its contract correctly, this cannot change the semantics; `HashSet` will always behave exactly as if `.equals` were being called.

Comment: This is the same in python. I was looking for evidence though. Can you link any?

Comment: Look at the source code of `HashSet`, or actually, `HashMap`.  [Here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.containsKey%28java.lang.Object%29) is the source for `HashMap.containsKey`, which as stated, only looks in the same bucket, verifies that the hashes are exactly equal, and then tests if the objects are `==` before calling `equals`.

Comment: The real problem is the first check, which gives false even the two obejcts are equal by means of equals(). Which means == gives false and HashSet does not call equals. This is what I think does not conform with the contract.

Comment: @xing, then your objects violate their own contract for `hashCode()`. `HashSet` cannot work if your hash codes are invalid.  Any two objects that are `.equals` must have the same `hashCode()`.

Comment: I'm curious about the reason for the downvote.  I've already stated that according to the `Object` contract, if two objects have different hash codes they are not allowed to be `.equals`.

Comment: Yes that explains my questions. Thanks a lot!